# Woocommerce. How to add a slider to a special category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to add a slider to a category page in full width of content? Which hook will be correct?

Category 1 - Slider 1, category 2 - slider 2.

Slider: Meta Slider, storefront theme.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[metaslider id="77"]'); ?>
```

Like in this example:

[image: Example]

I tried:

```
add_action ( ' storefront_before_content ' , ' custom_slider_storefront ' );
function  custom_slider_storefront () {
    if (is_category ('dresses')) {
        echo do_shortcode ( " [metaslider id = 77] " );
    }
    else {}
}
```

Comment: What is the output? Do you get an error message?

Comment: There is no error message. But the slider does not appear on the category page.

Comment: Remove the spaces between id and 77. `[metaslider id=77]`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec nope, not true. Check the website https://www.metaslider.com/documentation/full-browser-width-meta-slider-using-template-includes/

Comment: All Wordpress shortcodes work this way… So there is an error in the documentation

Comment: In Wordpress Shordcode attribute values **need always to have `"` or `'` around** like `echo do_shortcode( "[metaslider id='77']" )` …

Comment: LoicTheAztec, yes you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the spaces in your add_action()

in Woocommerce you check the page for category with

```
if (is_product_category( 'dresses' )){}

// It should look like this
add_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'custom_slider_storefront' );
function custom_slider_storefront() {
    if (is_product_category('dresses')) {
        echo do_shortcode( "[metaslider id=77]" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me, please, how to do that the slider was after breadcrumb.

Comment: Thank you. To change the sequence, need to replace 'storefront_before_content' to 'storefront_content_top'.